Magento 2 : Add Store Language in URL's
I have two website example.com(store code is usa) and example.ca(store code is default)
both website in English language
This two website working fine, now I want to convert only example.ca to example.com/en-ca
How to do achieve this?
I tried to change default store base secure and unsecure url from store > configuration but css and js, images shows 404 in console at front
or should I look at into  class Magento\Store\Model\Store?
or should I rewrite code only in.htaccess file?
I am confused please help

So you want to added store code into URL.

Actually I achieved by creating folder en-ca in pub folder and added index.php and .htaccess file
add below code in pub/en-ca/index.php
then go canada store view configuration in admin panel and change the media and static url to https://example.com/media and https://example.com/static
<?php
/**
 * Public alias for the application entry point
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

try {
    require  '/chroot/home/ss7895/stagingwebsite/pub/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base'; //Webite code as same in admin panel
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
 


You need to follow this steps.

Make your default store code to "en-ca"

Then follow this steps.

Navigate to Stores > Configuration > General > Web and find the URL Options section.
There you choose to Add Store Code to URLs selecting Yes from the
corresponding select box and Save Config.


thank you for your answer, but I achieved without enable store code because Add store code to url is global configuration and it enable by default for all stores
